# Is there any way to change the order of Grafana panel stacked series that come from the same PromQL query?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

This is very easy when there are multiple queries (just drag and drop up or down), but I don't know how to do it when all those series come from the same query.

Example:

If I do this 3 queries separately I can order of panel series:

```
s3_fetchs_durations_bucket{le="0.001"}
s3_fetchs_durations_bucket{le="0.01"} 
s3_fetchs_durations_bucket{le="0.1"}
```

If I do this this single query I get all the same results but no control of series order:

```
s3_fetchs_durations_bucket
```